# Advice on array subtraction in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help or advice how to improve below formula:

```
 =TEXT(SUMPRODUCT((B2:O2*(MOD(COLUMN(B2:O2);2)=1))-(B2:O2*(MOD(COLUMN(B2:O2);2)=0)))/(COUNTIF(B2:O2;"<>")/2);"d ""Days"", h""h"" mm""min""")
```

Above formula works only if there are even number of pairs.

My goal is to get difference between dates and then get average of that difference. There can be unknown number of columns. Simplified approach shown below:

Sum((Z1-Y1)+(Y1-X1)+(X1-W1)+(...)+(B1-A1))/26

Screen shot of sample data below:

Row 1: even number of time entries

Row 2: uneven number and the formula fails

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your "simple formula", couldn't `(Z1-Y1)+(Y1-X1)+(X1-W1)+(...)+(B1-A1)` be drastically simplified to `Z1-A1`?

Comment: @Peter - Boom, maths! Nice thinking.

Comment: @BruceWayne I can't tell if you are being sarcastic or not haha

Comment: @Peter - I'm not! I often get so fixed on a formula work/not working, I forget to take a step back and realize I can make it much simpler...like your suggestion on that long formula. :D

Comment: Guys thanks for comments, but with simple one ((Z1-Y1)+(...)+(B1-A1))  I need to get each pairs time difference and then I need to get all those differences average. So Z1-A1 does not work. I was thinking about OFFSET, but with my tries had no good outcome. Any help with more sophisticated one is appreciated.

Comment: Mathematically, `(Z1-Y1)+(Y1-X1)+(X1-W1)+(...)+(B1-A1)` is equal to `Z1-A1`. If you are saying that it doesn't work, it just means you haven't worded the question correctly. Please revise question to correct formula.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope it now clarifies why (Z1-Y1)+(Y1-X1)+(X1-W1)+(...)+(B1-A1) is not equal to Z1-A1 @Peter

Comment: Looks like all you did was put parentheses around it and divide by 26? If anything that would just change it to (Z1-A1)/26. I think some of your 1's in this formula need to change to 2's.

Comment: This is reference to excel columns/rows.. In the sample its array from Z-A (26 letters) again just for reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have a different solution for you.

Basically the formula you can try is this (you may need to replace `,` with `;` due to locale problem):

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(ISODD(COLUMN(B2:O2))*(B2:O2)-ISEVEN(COLUMN(B2:O2))*(B2:O2))/IF(ISODD(COUNTA(B2:O2)),(COUNTA(B2:O2)-1)/2,COUNTA(B2:O2)/2),"d ""Days"", h""h"" mm""min""")
```

As you can see the pic below, you will get the result you want.  What this does is to use `odd columns (C, E, G etc.)` to subtract `even columns (B, D, F etc.)` and then take the average.  Believe it or not, highlight the green cells and you should find out the average number is what you are looking for.

[image]

However, for some examples you don't have paired columns and the last column needs to be ignored.  And that is why you see that `COUNTA` and `COUNTIF` just to determine if the last column needs to be dropped from the formula.

Another thing to note is the column range.  I used `OFFSET` to find the range that needs to be evaluated in the formula due to that paired columns issue.  And therefore, those four `B2:O2's` inside `SUMPRODUCT` were replaced by `=OFFSET(A2,,1,,IF(ISODD(COUNTA(B2:O2)),COUNTA(B2:O2)-1,COUNTA(B2:O2)))`.

Here is the **final formula** you can try:

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(ISODD(COLUMN(OFFSET(A2,,1,,IF(ISODD(COUNTA(B2:O2)),COUNTA(B2:O2)-1,COUNTA(B2:O2)))))*(OFFSET(A2,,1,,IF(ISODD(COUNTA(B2:O2)),COUNTA(B2:O2)-1,COUNTA(B2:O2))))-ISEVEN(COLUMN(OFFSET(A2,,1,,IF(ISODD(COUNTA(B2:O2)),COUNTA(B2:O2)-1,COUNTA(B2:O2)))))*(OFFSET(A2,,1,,IF(ISODD(COUNTA(B2:O2)),COUNTA(B2:O2)-1,COUNTA(B2:O2)))))/IF(ISODD(COUNTA(B2:O2)),(COUNTA(B2:O2)-1)/2,COUNTA(B2:O2)/2),"d ""Days"", h""h"" mm""min""")
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks! It works.  I'am really interested in offset approach so will study it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(COUNT(B2:O2));TEXT(SUMPRODUCT((B2:O2*(MOD(COLUMN(B2:O2);2)=1))-(B2:O2*(MOD(COLUMN(B2:O2);2)=0)))/(COUNTIF(B2:O2;"<>")/2);"d ""Days"", h""h"" mm""min""");TEXT(SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("B"&(INDEX(ROW();1))&":"&ToColletter(COUNT(B2:O2))&(INDEX(ROW();1)))*(MOD(COLUMN(INDIRECT("B"&(INDEX(ROW();1))&":"&ToColletter(COUNT(B2:O2))&(INDEX(ROW();1))));2)=1))-(INDIRECT("B"&(INDEX(ROW();1))&":"&ToColletter(COUNT(B2:O2))&(INDEX(ROW();1)))*(MOD(COLUMN(INDIRECT("B"&(INDEX(ROW();1))&":"&ToColletter(COUNT(B2:O2))&(INDEX(ROW();1))));2)=0)))/((COUNTIF(B2:O2;"<>")-1)/2);"d ""Days"", h""h"" mm""min"""))
```

help function:

```
Public Function ToColletter(Collet)
    ToColletter = Split(Cells(1, Collet).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

[image]